# Compile Error Getting when i try to read firebase data using esp32 in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32

I am trying to read the firebase data using esp32, when i try to read firebase data statically(string literal) no error is coming.

```
String board=Firebase.getString(fbdo, F("Device/board")) ? String(fbdo.to()).c_str() : fbdo.errorReason().c_str(); //getting data successfully
```

But when i try to read data dynamically using String object, i am getting compile error for given code

```
String string2 = "Device/board"; 
String board1=Firebase.get(fbdo, F(string2)) ? String(fbdo.to()).c_str() : 
    fbdo.errorReason().c_str();

ERROR : #define F(string_literal) (FPSTR(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: add to the question the exact error message you get

Comment: don't use the F macro on esp32

Answer (score 0):

The macro `F()` can only be used with string literals, not with variables.

A simple solution should be (I cannot test) to provide `string2` directly. (I hope that `Firebase.get()` is overloaded.) Try this:

```cpp
String board1 = Firebase.get(fbdo, string2) ? String(fbdo.to()).c_str() : fbdo.errorReason().c_str();
```

To save precious RAM, you might consider to use another data type for `string2`. To get a similar result, you could try:

```cpp
const __FlashStringHelper *string2 = F("Device/board");
String board1 = Firebase.get(fbdo, string2) ? String(fbdo.to()).c_str() : fbdo.errorReason().c_str();
```

---

To gain some more insight, you might like to read [this guide on PROGMEM](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html).

Comment: Thank you bro, i will test it and let you know the result